# Django form, not getting rendered in a template

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a simple form with a single text input field which is not getting displayed in the template.Only the form's submit button is displayed.

The template:

```
<form method='POST' action="example">
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

The form:

```
class sampleform(forms.Form):
data = forms.CharField(label = u'Add a text:')
```

The view:

```
def example(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
      form = sampleform(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid:
         return HttpResponseRedirect('/register/success/')
   else:
      form = sampleform()
      variables = RequestContext(request,{'form':form})
   return render_to_response('stream.html',variables)
```

Comment: Try return render(request, 'stream.html', { 'form': form })

Comment: @jarmod Tried and that was not working.

Comment: I would simplify, for example use the simplest CharField (no widget) and check what you're doing against the doc at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/.  Get the most basic thing working then enhance.  Also load the web page in Chrome or Firefox with debugging so that you can detect any errors in the page.

Comment: @jarmod I have made the changes as you can see above. Still its doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I also get such a bug, tried to change forms, at first I had a form.ModelForms, Then tried in new forms.Form, but it was still not out in template.

**I win my bug when in View change Context {'form':form} to {'formZZZ':form} and template to {{ formZZZ }}, and 2 forms still work (Forms and ModelForms).**

Question was 4 years ago, but hope it help for other, who take this result. Python 3.5, virtualenv on Win10, Django 1.11.1 Sorry for bad English.